# Linq-to-SQL cast exception with stored procedure that returns unnamed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I don't own the SP, but it returns a dataset with columns with names like:

```
FileID, SomethingNormal, Foo, Bar, SUM(bleh)
```

`SUM(bleh)` is unnamed. I add the stored proc using the dbml tool in VS2010 and it detects `SUM(bleh)` as `Column1` and gives it an int type, which sounds alright.

However, when trying to run, the moment it tries to get the `IEnumerable`, it breaks by giving an error:

> Specified cast is not valid.
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is
>   not valid.    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)    at
>   Read_RejectedRecordsHourlyBySubscriptionResult(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()

That happens the moment I try to iterate or if I get the enumerate manually.

In a dev environment I did `SUM(bleh) as TotalBleh` (rest assured all this names are fake >_>) and I had no issues with what I've done.

Anything I should know? Thanks!

EDIT:

This appears to be a bug with Linq-to-SQL. Strangely, the bug report says it supports -ONE- anonymous column (although no more) and in this case there is only one.

I will do it with basic `SqlCommand` and stuff. So much for commodity.

Comment: A quick bit of Googling finds [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/325423/linq-generated-classes-cannot-handle-stored-procedures-that-produce-a-result-table-with-an-unnamed-column) and [this](http://blog.sublogic.com/2009/05/15/linq-to-sql-bug-with-stored-procedures-sprocs-must-have-named-columns-in-returned-result-sets/).

Comment: Just use column indexs: 1,2,3...

Comment: Please provide your LINQ query.

Comment: This is a 2.5 years old question. I don't even have access to that code anymore.